# What exactly does this kind of operation do?

Tags: pointers, bit-shift

I have this code, where wAddress is a pointer to a uint16_t variable.

```
uint8_t upperByte = *wAddress >> 8; 
uint8_t lowerByte = *wAddress;
```

Does the first shift operation overwrite the value in the variable, pointed by the wAddress?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that code came from C or C++ (which is an assumption that is worth pointing out because different languages handle syntax, operators, and order of operations differently), then no, the first shift does not overwrite the value in the variable. Rather, the shift overwrites the bits in the register.

When your code is

```
uint16_t someInt = 61590; // Binary: 1111 0000 1001 0110
uint16_t *wAddress = &someInt;
uint8_t upperByte = *wAddress >> 8; 
uint8_t lowerByte = *wAddress;
```

When compiled to ASM, this is first going to load the value referenced by `wAddress` which is *61590*. Once that value is in the register, it will shift to the right by 8 bits, which means the bottom 8 bits will be replaced by the top 8 bits, and the top 8 will be filled in with zeroes inside of the register. I.e., `0000 0000 1111 0000` (which is 240 in decimal). Then the the value will be truncated to the new bottom 8 bits and saved as the value of the `upperByte` variable.

After this, another copy of `someInt` will be loaded into the register, and this time the top 8 bits will be discarded with the bottom 8 bits being placed as the value of `lowerByte`, since no shift took place.

To actually overwrite the value of `someInt`, you would have to explicitly say `someInt = *wAddress >> 8;` otherwise, only a copy of the value stored in `someInt` is modified, rather than the value pointed to by `wAddress` itself.